# How do I get rid of the Bootstrap thumbnail from my webpage

Tags: html, css

[image]

So I have a basic website that uses style sheets from. Bootstrap.com

Of course when I send the link on Messenger I get the thumbnail above. Anyway to remove that thumbnail?

Thanks

Comment: did get what you saying , shall we see a link of your site or code or something

Comment: I think what he is trying to say is, while sharing the link of his website, he needs to remove thumbnail that appears for a link when we share it on social media (as mentioned in the above screenshot).

Comment: Pretty sure messenger uses the `meta` tags to help scrape this information from your site. See this [page](https://www.adhesion.co.nz/blog/how-to-change-website-thumbnail-in-facebook-post) for more details

Comment: For that you can use `meta` tag that can be added in the `header` or the `head` of your HTML

Comment: Within the header I have added:    
`<meta property="og:image" content="my img url"/>
  <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
   <meta property="og:title" content="my website name" />
   <meta property="og:url" content="my website name" />
   <meta property="og:description" content="my website name" /> `

And still I can't get rid of that bootstrap image

Comment: @SergioD.Caplan are there any other meta tags? Could you possibly share your code?

Comment: Zero other meta tags....

All there is are links to the bootstrap site which seem to overrule any meta tags for some reason?


`    <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/starter-template/">

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/examples/starter-template/starter-template.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: So for what it's worth here's how I fixed it.  I used the FB Sharing debugger, below and it saw none of my meta tags.  So I moved them all to the very end of the head section.  And somehow that worked.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/

Answer (score 0):

So for what it's worth here's how I fixed it. I used the FB Sharing debugger, below and it saw none of my meta tags. So I moved them all to the very end of the head section. And somehow that worked.

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing